# Install yara-python gives "Cannot open include file: 'openssl/asn1.h'" on Windows 11

Tags: python, yara

When I try to install yara-python by issuing the following command:

```
C:\Users\admin\code\my-project\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install yara-python
```

I get the following error message:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBUCKETS_128=1 -DCHECKSUM_1B=1 -DUSE_WINDOWS_PROC=1 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHASH_MODULE=1 -DHAVE_WINCRYPT_H=1 -DDOTNET_MODULE=1 -Iyara/libyara/include -Iyara/libyara/ -I. -IC:\Users\admin\code\limacharlie-signatures\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcyara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.obj
  authenticode.c
  yara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.c(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/asn1.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

I have installed Visual Studio Installer with Visual Studio Build Tools 2022.
I have addded "Desktop development with C++" and the optional addons `Windows 11 SDK`, `Windows 10 SDK` and `MSVC v142`.

[image]

However I get error when trying to install yara-python.

Complete error message:

```
Collecting yara-python
  Using cached yara-python-4.3.0.tar.gz (537 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: yara-python
  Building wheel for yara-python (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for yara-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for yara-python
Failed to build yara-python
Installing collected packages: yara-python
  Running setup.py install for yara-python: started
  Running setup.py install for yara-python: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [180 lines of output]
  C:\Users\admin\code\limacharlie-signatures\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
    warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'yara' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\console
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\demo
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\dotnet
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\elf
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\hash
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\math
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\pe
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\string
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\tests
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\time
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\proc
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\tlshc
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBUCKETS_128=1 -DCHECKSUM_1B=1 -DUSE_WINDOWS_PROC=1 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHASH_MODULE=1 -DHAVE_WINCRYPT_H=1 -DDOTNET_MODULE=1 -Iyara/libyara/include -Iyara/libyara/ -I. -IC:\Users\admin\code\limacharlie-signatures\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcyara-python.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara-python.obj
  yara-python.c
  yara-python.c(1527): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(1556): warning C4090: 'initializing': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(1597): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(1626): warning C4090: 'initializing': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(1942): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  yara-python.c(1943): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'uint8_t', possible loss of data
  yara-python.c(2187): warning C4047: '==': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
  yara-python.c(2823): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(2824): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(2858): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  yara-python.c(2859): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBUCKETS_128=1 -DCHECKSUM_1B=1 -DUSE_WINDOWS_PROC=1 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHASH_MODULE=1 -DHAVE_WINCRYPT_H=1 -DDOTNET_MODULE=1 -Iyara/libyara/include -Iyara/libyara/ -I. -IC:\Users\admin\code\limacharlie-signatures\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcyara\libyara\ahocorasick.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\ahocorasick.obj
  ahocorasick.c
  
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBUCKETS_128=1 -DCHECKSUM_1B=1 -DUSE_WINDOWS_PROC=1 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHASH_MODULE=1 -DHAVE_WINCRYPT_H=1 -DDOTNET_MODULE=1 -Iyara/libyara/include -Iyara/libyara/ -I. -IC:\Users\admin\code\limacharlie-signatures\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcyara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.obj
  authenticode.c
  yara\libyara\modules\pe\authenticode-parser\authenticode.c(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/asn1.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

yara-python

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```